# Does FASTMM4 and FASTMM5 work under Android/Ios?

Tags: delphi

Does FASTMM4 and FASTMM5 work under Android/Ios ? Else what is the memory manager used under those platforms ?

Comment: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Memory_Management

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FastMM5 seems to be for Windows only.

FastMM4 used to work on Linux via Kylix (a lot of time ago), but last time I checked its code was not compatible with the new Delphi POSIX units.

Personally, I [ended up making a fork in pure asm of FastMM4](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot2/blob/master/src/core/mormot.core.fpcx64mm.pas) - with some improvements for new CPUs and multi-threads scaling - to have a fast Windows and POSIX compatible MM on x86_64, but with FPC only.

On POSIX systems like Android or iOS, [Delphi calls the `libc` memory manager](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Memory_Management), which is a good and stable solution. The MM won't be the bottleneck of your Delphi Android/iOS application, so I would not loose time trying anything else.

Comment: woow you do a fork in pure ASM? you are a warrior :) If one day you have some time you can try to compare your fork with TBBmm (delphi implementation here: https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe/blob/master/source/ALTbbMM.pas). I found that this library have astomishing result in multithread compared to fastmm4 (didn't compare yet to fastmm5)

Comment: @zeus From my tests some years ago, Intel TBB is fast, but tends to consume a lot of RAM (GBs instead of MBs) on heavily multi-thread servers, and does panic/SIG_KILL on any GPF - which is a showstopper for any production service IMHO. And I would never use Win32 app for a server, only a Linux or BSD 64-bit system.

Comment: yes I confirm it's use a lot of RAM (but nowadays ram is very cheap) . Regarding GPF I never encounter it and I have heavy multi-thread servers online for several years (never never have even one). Win64 is not really a bad choice for a server, linux on delphi is still not very mature and I want only fullstack developpement from server to client so delphi from end to end